# How to add a column with the generated value that equals the number of row

Tags: dataframe, sas

My data looks like:

```
var1  |  var2  |  var3
1       |1        |1
1       |1       |1
1       |1        |1
1       |1        |1
1       |1        |1
1       |1        |1
```

I want to add new column named `id` that will have generated value equal to the count of the row. I want the data above to look like:

```
id  |  var1  |  var2  | var3
1       |1       |1         |1
2       |1        |1         |1
3      |1        |1         |1
4       |1       |1         |1
5       |1        |1         |1
6      |1       |1         |1
```

Comment: Those are all ones? Do you want to add 1 or a different value for each ID? What about multiple records of the same ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to add a variable that increments once for each observation? You can use a `sum` statement.

```
data want;
  id+1;
  set have;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Id = _N_` Also var1 and var2 are flipped in your output,. Is that a requirement?

Comment: Relating to `Also var1 and var2 are flipped in your output,. Is that a requirement?` No, I did it by mistake.

Comment: Not the \_N_ is just a counter of the number of iterations of the data step.  Depending on the complexity of the data step (is the SET statement executed conditionally?) it might not actually match observations in either the input or the output dataset.